# CIFAR10 takes too long to download. Can it be manually installed? Using Python 3.8.5 64-bit with Tensorflow/Keras

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow-datasets, python-3.8

As the title suggests, I was trying to install CIFAR10 with Tensorflow using

```
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import cifar10
cifarData = cifar10.load_data()
```

However I am getting times of >8 hours for download. I've heard you can place a manual download in a folder and it will be detected, but it did not seem to work. Is there anyway to manually unpack and place, or an actual place to put the file to be detected?

Comment: why do I spend only 3 mins to load the data? is there something wrong with your internet connection?

Comment: I think it's just python. Takes me only 1 minute to download it manually, but using Python, it only goes at like 10KBps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally when I tried downloading through a Python program it said it would take >8 hours. I did it through the console, and it took 3 minutes. In the console I typed in

```
python -c "from tensorflow.keras.datasets import cifar10; cifarData = cifar10.load_data()"
```

and it downloaded to "C:\Users\(MY USERNAME)\.keras\datasets" as both "cifar-10-batches-py.tar.gz" (the download) and "cifar-10-batches-py" (the unpackaged file). So if you want to manually install it, it should go there.

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks!
It threw certificate error though which I took care of by adding the following two lines in the beginning:
`import ssl`
`ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context`